# Image Thumbs catalog in DIEM CMS 5

Tags: symfony, symfony-1.4, diem-cms

I'm currently working with the DIEM 5 CMS system, and my problem is finding how to properly set up a catalog for the image thumbnails. The catalog is outside the main (root/uploads) website catalog and this is my problem. When I create the new catalog via FTP and copy files (web/uploads) it's showing the error "Forbidden 403".

How can I move the uploads catalog?

[image: DIEM CMS Catalog structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the file permissions of the upload folder allow for this. A 403 error indicates a permissions issue.

Comment: The problem is that thumbs are created and saved to this /uploads catalog and anyway any new picture is stored there. What I can do to change image catalog?

Comment: You mean you want to change the images stored in /uploads folder which is outside /web folder?

Comment: Yes I want to change image folder to /web/uploads